# Equipping Items

Tags: dark-souls-2

I can't believe this is stumping me but I can't seem to figure out how to equip multiple item from my inventory. I can use them from the inventory screen but I can't see how to actually equip them to use on the fly. Playing on 360

Answer (score 1):

On the screen where you equip weapons and armor, the bottom left most part of the screen contains 10 "belt" slots. If you select one of those, you can pick a consumable item to go in the slot that you can then use on the fly.

Comment: And you switch between them using the down button on the d-pad

Answer (score -1):

No, I do it straight from the inventory menu
Drink potion and unequip and re-equip attire before exiting menu. Was what I read to do on a site. And it works. Just the items cap at a certain % each time. And require me to make new ones with a new higher foritify enchantong potion and get a higher base % before i can get it higher than the last attire. Its not costly just mostly annoying lol. Plus at my level cant get falmer helmets that let u have a criclet as well equip